# Web API MVC5 using Swagger not going to call API with "Try it out!" with Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, swagger-2.0, webapi

- I configured Swagger UI in my Web API MVC5. For testing API's, swagger works fine until I add some header parameters.
- API's are created in such way that username & password fields are in headers and all other data is taken in the body.
- Headers are added by `IOperationFilter` as suggested in [Web Api How to add a Header parameter for all API in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493130/web-api-how-to-add-a-header-parameter-for-all-api-in-swagger)
  and `OperationFilter` is added in `SwaggerConfig.cs` as: `c.OperationFilter<AddHeaderParameters>();`

  ```
  public class AddHeaderParameters : IOperationFilter
  {
      public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
      {
          if (operation.parameters == null)
              operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

          operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
          {
              name = "Account Username",
              @in = "header",
              type = "string",
              required = true,
          });
          operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
          {
              name = "Account Password",
              @in = "header",
              type = "string",
              required = true,
          });
      }
  }
  ```

**Swagger UI with Headers**
[image]

Required help that which thing I have missed or something done not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution of issue facing as mentioned above in the question. Sharing here might be helpful for others.

As I created the class `AddHeaderParameters` for getting headers in swagger UI, I had given the header name self defined (that was actual cause of issue). The header name supposed to match as actual header name.

In my case, e.g. Header name was `AccountUserName`, which I used in swagger header with giving space as `Account Username`.

Correct way

```
operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
{
    name = "AccountUserName",
    @in = "header",
    type = "string",
    required = true,
});
```

Comment: yes I used swagger but did not return headers with multiple letters so it is informative &  beneficial.