# Require request header for asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, request-headers

I’m trying to get some direction as to where I could configure a set of webapi’s to require a set of request headers we’ll need for tracing purposes. We’re required to also generate a OpenAPI spec for these.

I’ve tried the approach here:

[Web Api How to add a Header parameter for all API in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493130/web-api-how-to-add-a-header-parameter-for-all-api-in-swagger)

But this only generates the spec and doesn’t enforce the identified headers to be provided.

I did try the approach using the FromHeader attribute at the controller level which did cover both of my requirements but I need to be able to configure these headers using the appsettings configuration.

Is tapping into swagger and writing a custom middleware the only way to achieve what I’m looking for?

Thank you in advanced!