# NET Core Web API how to add common header in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I have a requirement to add a common header in swagger. I have tried IOperationFilter but it is asking every API call. I need to add a header like a bearer token.

Comment: _"I have tried IOperationFilter but it is asking every API call."_ What do you mean "but is asking every API call"?

Comment: @Ashok take a look for this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493260/3520507. You can add non-required header `Required = false` in swagger with `IOperationFilter`. Also there are a lot of other ways to do this, describes in the answers